# Load images from specific URL in Adobe Edge Animate CC

Tags: html, url, adobe-edge, loadimage

I am creating a HTML5 banner and one of the specification is that all images shall be load from an URL. I am not a developer and I don't know how to do that by writing code.
Does anybody knows if this is possible to do in the some software without coding from scratch? If not, how is the way to do this?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do it with code I'm afraid. It's not too difficult though. 
So I am assuming you have built your banner using copies of the images locally, on your computer and that the same images also exist on a server for which you already have the absolute path.

Let's say, for the purpose of this explanation, that your project file is called **MyBanner.an** and the URL for the images is:
**http://www.bannerimages.com/images**

You will need a text editor (I like Sublime Text) and in the files published from edge you will see a file called:
MyBanner_edge.js

Next, find the bit of code that looks like this:

var im='images/'

Then change it to this:

var im='http://www.bannerimages.com/images/'

Be careful not to accidentaly remove the final slash or the quote marks. Then save the file and upload to the server.

Hope that works for you!
:)